# Javascript promise to iterate/include dynamic number of Arguments

Tags: node.js, sql-server, promise, azure-sql-database, tedious

I'm using the mssql npm module (with Tedious driver) to read/write to Azure Sql database from my node Server.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

All the examples I've found provide an hardcoded example of the query whether to read or write records, like this:

```
var insertRecordIntoTable = function (callback) {

  sql.connect(dbConfig).then(pool => {

     return pool.request()
        .input('ID', sql.Int, 210)
        .input('Name', sql.NVarChar, "John Doe")
        .input('EmailAddress', sql.NVarChar, "test@test.com")
        .query("INSERT INTO Accounts (ID, Name, EmailAddress) VALUES (@ID, @Name, @EmailAddress)")
  }).then(result => {
     console.dir(result)
     callback(result);
  }).catch(err => {
     // ... error checks
     console.log("Error occured: " + err);
     callback(err);
  });

}
```

Obviously, I'd like to write one standard method to **write records** to any table in the database.

Now I can fetch structure of each table and use that to find how what datatype each field should be from the key in jsonRecord and write something like this:

```
var insertRecordIntoTable = function (jsonRecord, tableName, callback) {

  let arrKeys = jsonRecord.allKeys();
  let columnNames = getCommaSeparatedColumnNames(arrKeys); 
  let valuePlaceholders = getValuePlaceholdersForSql(arrKeys);

  sql.connect(dbConfig).then(pool => {

     return pool.request()

        // how do I write something like this so that dynamic number of fields and values get populated in the query inside this promise.
        // I'm open to methods without promise as well.

        for(let x=0; x < arrKeys.length; x++){

           let key = arrKeys[x];

           // .input('ID', sql.Int, 210)
           .input(key, getTypeForKey(key, tableName), jsonRecord[ key ] )

        }

        .query("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columnNames + ") VALUES (" + valuePlaceholders + ")")
  }).then(result => {
     console.dir(result)
     callback(result);
  }).catch(err => {
     // ... error checks
     console.log("Error occured: " + err);
     callback(err);
  });

}

function getTypeForKey(key){. // looks up table schema and returns keyType }

function getCommaSeparatedColumnNames(arrKeys){  return arrKeys.join(", "); }

function getValuePlaceholdersForSql(arrKeys){   // write code to append '@' before every key and then join using comma's and return that string }
```

I'm sure node.js writing to SQL is a fairly common functionality and there may be better ways to achieve what I'm trying to do here. Please feel free to go a different route.

P.S. - Although I should say that I prefer **mssql** over **Tedious** package. It just seems better in functionality after going through the documentation in the last several hours.

Comment: Libraries that do this are usually called ORM.  (eg https://sequelize.org/) If you do a search for ORM Node.js I expect you will find what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Hogan. I knew there had to be something for this, just didn't know where to look. I'll look into Sequalize and the likes and revert with an update.

Comment: It is also easy to write your own ORM in modern languages -- I wrote one in in C# that fit in 150 lines.  I keep planning on making a version node of it but have not gotten a chance.  Here is the open source if you are interested in using it as a template: https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/b7f5c5e8dde61ae3cd6f

Comment: Thanks @Hogan. I glanced over it, looks good. I'll see if I can circle back to it next month. (Got deliverables that'll keep me busy the next few weeks.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interact with your database without creating all the queries by yourself, you can use a query builder like `knex` to manage the data as objects:

```
knex('Accounts').insert({ID: 210, Name: "John Doe", EmailAddress: "test@test.com"})
```

Would be similar to:

```
insert into `Accounts` (`EmailAddress`, `ID`, `Name`) values ('test@test.com', 210, 'John Doe')
```

Also I see you are checking types. If you need validation, maybe a complete ORM (I like [Objection.js](https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/)) would be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks @Rashomon. Those two look like good options. I'll look into them and revert with an update.